# Wordpress login error - uploads folder must be writable

Tags: wordpress

When I try to login wordpress site through wp-admin, getting the error message: **Uploads folder /home/mykeys/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallexport must be writable**

Server side, I have changed the permissions to 775 for wpallexport and all its child and parent folders but facing the same issue. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the plugin wp-all-export and it is working fine now. .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went to hosting files and renamed the folder temporarily. It worked for me.